# Android room LiveData receive the last change value on observe & how to discard db change value which observe before

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I use room return livedata like:

```
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM msg")
    LiveData<List<Msg>> loadMsgs();
```

In activity A, I insert msg MA into db, then In activity B, I observe livedata like:

```
        liveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), myProducts -> {
            if (myProducts != null) {

            }
        });
```

and insert msg MB into db in activityB.
First time I receive the only msg MA, second time I receive MA and MB,  why ? the msg MA is insert db before observe, I want receive all msg first time after observe.

Comment: I mean, you are doing a query. What would you expect to happen ?

Comment: @Blackbelt Fisrt time, I receive the only msg MA, I want receive all msg in db

Comment: shouldn't then be `LiveData<List<Msg>> loadMsgs()` ?

Comment: Yes, but second time has all msg

Comment: @Blackbelt sorry about it, I write wrong, In code, I was write LiveData<List<Msg>> loadMsgs()